# dpkg error code (1) uninstalling a package

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg, vnc, locale

I had an error installing a program, and the process is incomplete.

I tried to remove it using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge realvnc-vnc-server
```

Then, it gives me this:

```
apt-listchanges: Can't set locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct!
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "es_EC.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "es_EC.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "es_EC.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "es_EC.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "es_EC.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "es_EC.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "es_EC.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "es_EC.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "es_EC.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_GB.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package realvnc-vnc-server (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 realvnc-vnc-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Hope somebody can help me to fix this, and install it again.

Comment: Try sudo apt remove --purge realvnc-vnc-server and tell me if that works, if so, i will make that an answer.

Comment: @RayAntebioni it doesn't

Comment: try sudo apt install --reinstall realvnc-vnc-server and then do what you did before

Comment: Can't tell if it's related, but your locale is broken. To fix it, run the command `sudo locale-gen es_EC.UTF-8`